# Searching for tag shows both questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

When you search for a tag, for example [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app) it will show both questions and answers.

When searching meta this means duplicates in general since the number of questions isn't that high.

Can only questions be shown when searching for a tag?

Comment: Yes, just include `is:question` as well...

Comment: First thing I always do is add `is:q` indeed.

Comment: Should you consider this a feature or a bug?

Comment: I was going to submit a bug report about seeing duplicated questions when searching for a tag. Now I've realized that they weren't duplicates, but questions and answers shown separately... It's confusing because on web version you would see only the questions.

Comment: You are right. That is also confusing to me. So I will stick with the bug tag then.

Comment: I'll look into this - the app search should behave like the site search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in the next build (0.1.55+).